# Error while collecting the data from dataframe column in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

i am using Pyspark (Python 3.7 with Spark 2.4) and have a small line of code to collect a date from one of the attributes in Dataframe, i can run the same code from pyspark command line, however in my production code it errors out.

Here is the line of code where i read a dataframe "df" and collecting date from field "job_id".

```
>>> run_dt = map( lambda r:r[0], df.filter((df['delivery_date'] == '2017-12-31')).select(max(substring(df['job_id'], 9, 10).cast("integer")).alias('last_run')).collect())[0]
>>> print(run_dt)
2017123101
```

The same code line gives me an error in my production code while evaluation. The error message is-

```
  File "C:\Users\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 533, in collect
  File "C:\Users\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "C:\Users\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "C:\Users\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o68.collectToPython.
```

Comment: Did you already tried use another python version? Like python 3.5

Comment: can't use, that's the one i have to

Comment: I do not know if pyspark already works properly above version 3.5.2 of python, even in Databricks Platform they only support up to this version.